# How to define projection of a raster file in ecognition?

Tags: raster, georeferencing, ecognition

I have a raster file with no spatial reference. How can I define a projection for the image in ecognition software for classification purposes?

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem. Opening the same image in ArcGIS show the image is having projection system and completely alligns with the base map. whereas, when I open the same image in ecognition, it says co-ordinate system unknown.

Answer (score 3):

eCognition is not right place to pre-process input data. Currently, there is no option to georeference, project/reproject input data. The pre-processing operations like projection/reprojection, radiometric/atmospheric corrections etc. are supposed to be readily performed on input image data to work with.

The eCognition merely provides an option to whether use 'Geocoding' or not. It implies than you can still perform image segmentation and classification on input raster layers.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty certain that it's not possible with eCognition. You could try other software to define the coordinate system;

ArcGIS - "Define Coordinate System" tool

QGIS - If your raster file has no coordinate system, you will be prompted to select one. Then export the layer to a new file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I found a solution. The image has to be in **.img** format.

You should first use for example ArcGIS to composite bands: open ArcMap ---> then ArcToolbox--> Data Management Tools --> Raster --> Raster Prosessing --> Composite Bands (double click).

In the Composite Bands window as an Input Rasters, you should select the bands which need to composite (for example in my case: Sentinel-2 images, for Natural colors select S2B_MSIL2A_20200620T060639_N0214_R134_T42TWL_20200620T095034.SAFE --> GRANULE --> L2A_T42TWL_A017177_20200620T061633 --> IMG_DATA --> R10m --> press Ctrl and select B2, B3, B4 and press Add.

Next in the "**Output Raster**" field chouse your location folder, write the name of the image like:
naturalcolor**.img**

Then press OK! That's all. Just open this new image in eCognition and there will be your coordinate system.

*Note: .img — ERDAS IMAGINE*

Answer (score -1):

To define a projection system to raster you will have to geo reference the raster file. You can use Arcgis to accomplish this task.

Comment: There is no difference from @pgager's answer.